# Matplotlib Line Graph with Table from Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

Given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'YYYYMM':[201603,201503,201403,201303,201603,201503,201403,201303],
         'Count':[5,6,2,7,4,7,8,9],
         'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
df['YYYYMM']=df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2]
t=df.pivot_table(df,index=['YYYYMM'],columns=['Group'],aggfunc=np.sum)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
t.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

I'd like to add a summary table below it as a separate axis.

I would allocate the other axis via subplot2grid, but using subplots(2,1) will work as well as I can just adapt it to my needs.

I'd like the table to look like this:

```
   2013   2014   2015   2016
A   7      2       6      5
B   9      8       7      4
```

...with no borders/lines if possible.

**Update:**

Here's a sample of what I've tried with subplot2grid:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'YYYYMM':[201603,201503,201403,201303,201603,201503,201403,201303],
         'Count':[5,6,2,7,4,7,8,9],
         'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
df['YYYYMM']=df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2]
t=df.pivot_table(df,index=['YYYYMM'],columns=['Group'],aggfunc=np.sum)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(figsize), dpi=300)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((100,100), (0,0), rowspan=70, colspan=100)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((100,100), (80,0), rowspan=20, colspan=100)
t.plot(ax=ax1)

ax1.legend_.remove()
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False);ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False);ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False);ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False);ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False);ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False);ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
#ax1.xaxis.set_visible(False) #Hide x axis label
ax2.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.yaxis.set_visible(False)

ax1.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',bottom='on',top='off')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y',which='both',left='on',right='off')
ax2.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',bottom='off',top='off')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y',which='both',left='off',right='off')

from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
t2=df.pivot_table(df,index=['Group'],columns=['YYYYMM'],aggfunc=np.sum).sortlevel(ascending=False)

sns.heatmap(df,annot=True,fmt='d',linewidths=.5,cbar=False,cmap=ListedColormap(['white']))

plt.show()
```

...which produces this (notice that the bottom plot is hidden; this is intentional as I only want to display faint grey lines between rows and columns where absolutely needed (per Stephen Few - "Show Me The Numbers"). 
But I would like for the years in the table to align with the year index tick labels on the x-axis.

**Another update:**
Using Seaborn (see last 4 lines of code in update), I tried a heat map, which might get me to where I need to be. I just need to format the numbers, label the groups, and maybe shift the dates.

[image]

Comment: Please see update.